# Вывод DataGrid в Excel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagrid, closedxml

Нашел пример кода на другом сайте, но не понимаю как его объединить с кнопкой импорта данных. Подскажите?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С#

```
public static void SaveExcelData(List<Teacher> Data, string FileName)
        {
            var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Лист1");

            //Заголовки у столбцов
            worksheet.Cell("Имя преподавателя" + 1).Value = "Column1";
            worksheet.Cell("Фамилия преподавателя" + 1).Value = "Column2";
            worksheet.Cell("Отчество преподавателя" + 1).Value = "Column3";
            worksheet.Cell("Логин" + 1).Value = "Column4";
            worksheet.Cell("Пароль" + 1).Value = "Column5";
            int row = 2;

            //Запись данных 
            foreach (Teacher data in Data)
            {
                worksheet.Cell("Имя преподавателя" + row).Value = data.SurnameTeacher;
                worksheet.Cell("Фамилия преподавателя" + row).Value = data.FirstnameTeacher;
                worksheet.Cell("Отчество преподавателя" + row).Value = data.PatronymicTeacher;
                worksheet.Cell("Логин" + row).Value = data.LoginTeacher;
                worksheet.Cell("Пароль" + row).Value = data.PasswordTeacher;
                row++;
            }

            worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents(); //ширина столбца по содержимому

            workbook.SaveAs(@".\Курсовая работа рпит ТАБАРГИНА\" + FileName + ".xlsx");
        }

        private void Print_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ComboPrint.Text == "Word")
            {
                
            }
            if (ComboPrint.Text == "Excel")
            {
                SaveExcelData(List < Teacher > Data, string FileName);
            }
        }
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="GD" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" IsVisibleChanged="GD_IsVisibleChanged" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding SurnameTeacher}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding FirstnameTeacher}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Отчество" Binding="{Binding PatronymicTeacher}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Логин" Binding="{Binding LoginTeacher}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Пароль" Binding="{Binding PasswordTeacher}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">Способ экспорта данных:</TextBlock>
                
                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboPrint">
                <TextBlock>Word</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock>Excel</TextBlock>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: И опять вы наступаете на теж грабли. Вы создали свой собственный метод `public static void SaveExcelData(List<Teacher> Data, string FileName)`, который, как видите, должен принять коллекцию объектов `Teacher` и простую строку. Вы взяли, и тупо это скопировали `SaveExcelData(List < Teacher > Data, string FileName);`, а теперь подумайте, вы передаете тут данные? Разве данные так передаются? Да вроде нет... Так почему вы делаете опять, такую странную ошибку? У вас должно быть `var data = ...; var fileName = "..."; SaveExcelData(data, fileName);`, и опять, где получить это - ищите сами, ваш проект